# Using Hibernate tools Ant task from Gradle

Tags: hibernate, gradle

I would like to generate POJOs from an existing database using Hibernate and Gradle.  Gradle can easily call Ant tasks and Hibernate has ant tasks for reverse engineering databases.

I found this old Gradle task definition on the web and modified it for the newest version of Gradle but it doesn't work:

```
ant { 
    taskdef(name: 'hibernatetool', 
        classname: 'org.hibernate.tool.ant.HibernateToolTask', 
        classpath: configurations.compile.asPath )
    mkdir( dir: "$buildDir/generated" ) 
    hibernatetool( destdir : "$buildDir/generated" ) { 
        annotationconfiguration( configurationfile:"$classesDir/hibernate.cfg.xml" ) 
        hbm2ddl( export: false, outputfilename: 'schema.sql' ) 
        classpath { 
            pathelement( path: classesDir ) 
        } 
    } 
}
```

I get the error:

```
No such property: classesDir for class: org.gradle.api.internal.project.DefaultAntBuilder
```

How can I modify this to generate the schema file from the database? (I know this won't generate the POJOs yet, but it is the first step!)

My dependencies look like:

```
dependencies {
    compile 'org.hibernate:hibernate-tools:4.0.0-CR1'
    testCompile group: 'junit', name: 'junit', version: '4.10'
}
```

Comment: Well... I see that my question and the example gradle task are not addressing the same problem.  The hibernate hbml2ddl creates a ddl from entity classes, not from the database.

Comment: Which would also be why I later removed `classesDir` from the classpath, because I didn't need it for my use case. I did eventually get this working... but it looks a bit different than the above, of course.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

My guess is that you want to use the classes output directory from your main source set:

```
sourceSets.main.output.classesDir
```

If you just use `classesDir`, Gradle will try to resolve the field on the `AntBuilder` instance.

Comment: I ended up removing `classesDir` entirely. I'm not even sure why it's there, but I didn't need it. The above is generating a DDL, I'm generating Java sources from the database. I then copy the generated sources to another project... in fact, I copy them to both the client and server projects and the data is marshalled between them using the generated objects serialized to XML.